# Maximum update depth exceeded with useLayoutEffect, useRef

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I have the following component:

```
// component.js
import React from 'react';
import useComponentSize from 'useComponentSize';

const component = () => {
  const [comSize, comRef] = useComponentSize();

  return (
    <div style={{width: '100%'}} ref={comRef}>
      <p>hi</p>
    </div>
  );
};
```

which is using `useComponentSize`, a hook I've made:

```
// useComponentSize.js
import {
  useRef,
  useState,
  useLayoutEffect,
} from 'react';

const useComponentSize = () => {
  const [size, setSize] = useState({
    width: 0,
    height: 0,
  });
  const resizeRef = useRef();

  useLayoutEffect(() => {
    setSize(() => ({ 
      width: resizeRef.current.clientWidth,
      height: resizeRef.current.clientHeight,
    }));
  });
  
  return [size, resizeRef];
};

export default useComponentSize;
```

but for a reason I cannot work out, it always exceeds the maximum update depth. I've tried having `useLayoutEffect` depend upon `resizeRef`, which I thought would work, but then it doesn't update again (which upon reflection is exactly how I should have expected a ref to work).

What should I do to make this work properly, and most importantly why does the above cause an infinite loop?

---

Edit: second attempt using event listeners, still failing. What concept am I missing here?

```
// component.js
import React, { useRef } from 'react';
import useComponentSize from 'useComponentSize';

const component = () => {
  const ref = useRef();
  const [comSize] = useComponentSize(ref);

  return (
    <div style={{width: '100%'}} ref={ref}>
      <p>hi</p>
    </div>
  );
};
```

```
import {
  useRef,
  useState,
  useLayoutEffect,
} from 'react';

const useComponentSize = (ref) => {
  const [size, setSize] = useState();

  useLayoutEffect(() => {
    const updateSize = () => {
      setSize(ref.current.clientWidth);
    }
    
    ref.current.addEventListener('resize', updateSize);
    updateSize();
    
    return () => window.removeEventListener('resize', updateSize);
  }, []);
  
  return [size];
};

export default useComponentSize;
```

That edit above is based upon this [`useWindowSize`](https://usehooks.com/useWindowSize/) hook, which works great (I'm using it currently as a replacement, although I'd rather still get the above to work, and especially to know why it doesn't work).

---

A small explanation of what I'm trying to achieve as it wasn't made explicitly clear before: I want the state `size` to update whenever the size of the referenced component's size changes. That is, if the window resizes, and the component remains the same size, it should not update. But if the component size does change, then the `size` state should change value to reflect that.

Comment: Did you try `useEffect` instead of `useLayoutEffect` ?

Comment: Just tried - no dice

Comment: @pilchard I think that it's used for destruction. Let me check the docs again!

Comment: @Yousaf, I've tried your method too, and it only updates the first time. It doesn't update when I resize the component!

Comment: That solution doesn't observes the changes to the DOM elements. You can use `ResizeObserver` to get the initial size and also observe the changes. Try this [Demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/objective-franklin-5xc6w?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark)

Comment: Amazing Yousef, had never heard of it! If you put it as an answer I'll accept

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code gets stuck in an infinite loop because you haven't passed the dependency array to `useEffectLayout` hook.

You actually don't need to use `useEffectLayout` hook at all. You can observe the changes to the DOM element using [ResizeObserver API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ResizeObserver).

**P.S:** Although OP's problem has already been solved through a demo posted in one of the comments under the question, i am posting an answer for anyone who might look at this question in the future.

**Example:**

```js
const useComponentSize = (comRef) => {
  const [size, setSize] = React.useState({
    width: 0,
    height: 0
  });

  React.useEffect(() => {
    const sizeObserver = new ResizeObserver((entries, observer) => {
      entries.forEach(({ target }) => {
        setSize({ width: target.clientWidth, height: target.clientHeight });
      });
    });
    sizeObserver.observe(comRef.current);

    return () => sizeObserver.disconnect();
  }, [comRef]);

  return [size];
};

function App() {
  const comRef = React.useRef();
  const [comSize] = useComponentSize(comRef);

  return (
    <div>
      <textarea ref={comRef} placeholder="Change my size"></textarea>
      <h1>{JSON.stringify(comSize)}</h1>
    </div>
  );
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.13.1/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.13.1/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: You're totally right about `useLayoutEffect` - I was under the presumption that I needed `useEffect` to monitor changes, and `useLayoutEffect` as it needed to render the ref first. Thanks in particular for the correction, and pointing me to the observer